# How to Shallow Query Firebase Realtime Database While Maintaining Key Order

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am currently using the snapshot.forEach method to maintain order (which is essential in my application), but this requires me to do a snapshot deep query. Is there a way to do the same functionality without running a full deep query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only API surface that can get a key without its value from the Realtime Database is its REST API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow

The only (and default) ordering that happens there is by the node keys. Depending on the tool you use the read the JSON they may show up unordered there though, so you should always re-order them explicitly in your code, but you *can* use the key order to get a slice of the data with `startAfter` and `limitToFirst`.

---

An example, using this data from another question a while ago: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/70102492/Main/News/Categories/Education.json?print=pretty

You can get the first three node keys with: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/70102492/Main/News/Categories/Education.json?print=pretty&shallow=true&limitToFirst=3

And then the next three with: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/70102492/Main/News/Categories/Education.json?print=pretty&shallow=true&limitToFirst=3&startAfter=-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn

Comment: Note that startAfter and limitToFirst are not compatible with REST API shallow reads (as far as I can tell)

Comment: If you click the links in my answer that use those parameters, you can see that they actually make a difference on the result you get. If you're having a hard time making them work for your use-case, I recommend posting a new question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck.

Comment: "shallow cannot be used with any of the "filtering data" query parameters." from REST documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data. It just returns a console error.

Comment: Did you click the links in my answer? They are functioning and use `limitToFirst` and `startAfter` to get paginated results. Again: if that doesn't work for you in your use-case, please open a new question with a minimal repro that we can all look at in a similar way to how I did in my answer.

Comment: here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72987350/13397413