# Is it possible to use the REST API "shallow" feature with Firebase data filtering query parameters?

Tags: python, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

The documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data) for using REST to retrieve Firebase data explicitly states that 'shallow cannot be used with any of the "filtering data" query parameters'. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70174503/how-to-shallow-query-firebase-realtime-database-while-maintaining-key-order/70174811?noredirect=1#comment128909766_70174811) I am told that it is possible to run a shallow query with filters (e.g. limitToFirst, startAfter).

Running this:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

databaseReference = db.reference("/")

snapshot = databaseReference.child("Bot Applications").order_by_child("status").equal_to("ACTIVE").limit_to_first(self.applicationKeyCollectionCount).get(etag=False, shallow=True)
```

or

```
snapshot = databaseReference.child("Bot Applications").order_by_key().limit_to_first(self.applicationKeyCollectionCount).get(etag=False, shallow=True)
```

or any other simplified variation of this query results in an error message like

```
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'shallow'
```

or

```
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shallow'
```

or

```
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'etag'
```

The code runs successfully when the query has all filters removed like

```
snapshot = databaseReference.child("Bot Applications").get(etag=False, shallow=True)
```

or without the shallow feature like

```
snapshot = databaseReference.child("Bot Applications").order_by_child("status").equal_to("ACTIVE").limit_to_first(self.applicationKeyCollectionCount).get()
```

Is there an efficient way to somehow run a shallow FRTDB query with filters?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the REST API can filter on the data that it returns. So if you request a shallow result set, it can filter on keys only. That's also exactly what I do in the examples in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70174811) that you linked.

There is no way to do a shallow query and then filter on any of the properties under the keys that are returned.

Comment: Also, are you saying the documentation is incorrect? "shallow cannot be used with any of the "filtering data" query parameters." is inclusive of "limitToFirst, limitToLast, startAt, endAt, and equalTo" according to the documentation.

Comment: snapshot = databaseReference.child("Bot Applications").order_by_key().limit_to_first(self.applicationKeyCollectionCount).get(etag=False, shallow=True) does not work either. I tested this earlier. That is what you mean by "filter on keys only", correct? (forgot to write ".order_by_key()" in original comment)

Comment: If you think the documentation is incorrect, I recommend filing feedback with the button at the top of that page. It might have to read that you can't use `orderBy` on shallow queries, but honestly we'd also have to dig in and check exactly what is possible. My explanation above is why it works in the case that you linked though. --- My interpretation of why keys work is that you can only filter on what the API returns, which would explain why `etag` indeed doesn't work. And I doubt you can request `etag` on shallow queries, as that'd sort of defeat the purpose of allowing shallow queries here

Comment: Frank, I really appreciate all the times you've helped me directly and indirectly in the past, but I think we're on completely different wavelengths here. I think the documentation is right. I never requested etag, just set it =false as per the documentation example. I also tested this without defining the etag. Maybe this is a Python limitation or something, though the documentation seems to support my understanding of the issue in general. Ultimately, I was unsuccessful in shallow filtering by key or any other request variation. Anyways, thx for your feedback.

Comment: You asked "Is there an efficient way to somehow run a shallow FRTDB query with filters?", to which I answered "There is no way to do a shallow query and then filter on any of the properties under the keys that are returned." which is a slightly long version of saying "No, there isn't". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ --- I'm not sure what SDK you're using, so have only been focusing on the direct REST API without any wrappers. Did you try the closest equivalent to what I have in my answer that you linked, so *without* any `orderBy` and with just a `limitToFirst`?

Comment: So that might be: `databaseReference.child("Bot Applications").get(etag=False, shallow=True).limit_to_first(3)`.

Comment: Using the VS SDK. "limit_to_first()" in Python isn't recognized without a preceding "order_by_[ ]", much like with Java and Swift. I don't know anything about wrappers, but maybe they limit shallow read functionality?

Comment: It's more likely an oversight - as limiting a shallow query in the way I do in the answer you linked is definitely very uncommon. That said, I hoped I conclusively answered your question on whether it is possible to run a shallow query with filter on child properties.